# Python & Regex: Match all, but not when x or y

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have lines like this one:

```
 Test, Customer Relationship (CR), 4D-, 1D-, 3D-magnetic (circuit, simulation) Edyson, test
```

In these lines, I want to match every comma (,) with some exceptions: I don't want to match a comma preceeded by a minus (-,) or if it inside Brackets (... , ...).

So in the example line, only the first, the second, and the last comma should be a match.

I know how to match comma not preceeded by a minus:

```
(?<!\-)\,
```

But I don't know how to match only commas that are not between brackets, and I don't know how to combine the rules.

Can this be done in regex? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
r'(?<!-),(?![^()]*\))'
```

- `(?<!-)` is a negative lookbehind to avoid matching comma when preceded by hyphen
- `(?![^()]*\))` is a negative lookahead to avoid matching comma when it is with `(...)`

This is assuming you don't have unbalanced `(...)` text.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV4pY2/1)

**Example:**

```
>>> s = 'Test, Customer Relationship (CR), 4D-, 1D-, 3D-magnetic (circuit, simulation) Edyson, test'
>>> print re.sub(r'(?<!-),(?![^()]*\))', '\n', s)
Test
 Customer Relationship (CR)
 4D-, 1D-, 3D-magnetic (circuit, simulation) Edyson
 test
```

Comment: This will fails for nested brackets like `(circuit, simul()ation)`

Comment: In answer I've written my assumption that this is for balanced (and not nested) parentheses.

Comment: Yep, good job and upvote, but still is not a general answer ;-), although the general answer is out of the regex scope.

Comment: Perfect answer fo me: I don't have nested brackets, and it's good to know, that with nested brackets, it can't be done in pure regex anymore. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

With the last version of the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
import regex

s=' Test, Customer Relationship (CR), 4D-, 1D-, 3D-magnetic (circuit, simulation) Edyson, test'

reg = regex.compile(r'(?:\([^)]*\)|-,)(*SKIP)(*F)|,')
print(reg.split(s))
```

Comment: Never heard about this new RegEx Module! Won't deal with it in the current project, but good to know, there is something :-)